# Prove: $\mathbb{C}^{*} \cong U_1 \times \mathbb{R}^{*}_{> 0}$ (isomorph to circle group)

Tags: group-theory, functions, complex-numbers, group-isomorphism

> Define the circle group $U_1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| =1 \} \subset \mathbb{C}^*$. Prove: $\mathbb{C}^* \cong U_1 \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}^*$.

I would like to know if I did it correct. I believe I still have to say that my function is well-defined, but I don't know how to explain this, and for injectivity I would like to use that a function is injective if $\text{Ker}(f) = {0}$. I hope somebody can help me with this.

My idea:
Define $f: \mathbb{R}_{>0}^* \times U_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^* : (r, e^{2\pi ix}) \mapsto re^{2\pi i x}$. It's a function from a group mapping to a group.

1. $f$ is surjective, as every element in $\mathbb{C}^*$ can be written as $re^{2\pi i x}$ with $r > 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The element is mapped to $(r, e^{2\pi i x}).$
2. $f$ is a homomorphism: $f((r_1, e^{2\pi i x_1})(r_2, e^{2\pi i x_2})) = f(r_1r_2, e^{2\pi i(x_1 + x_2)}) = r_1r_2e^{2\pi(x_1 + x_2})$ and $f(r_1, e^{2\pi i x_1})f(r_2, e^{2\pi ix_2}) = r_1e^{2\pi i x_1}r_2e^{2\pi i x_2} = r_1r_2e^{2\pi i (x_1 + x_2)}$.
3. $f$ is injective when Ker$(f) = {e}$; $\mathbb{C}^*$ has 2 elements that satisfy $x^2 = e$, namely$x = 1$ and $x = -1$.

$\mathbb{R}_{>0}^* \times U_{1}$ also has two, namely $(1, 1)$ and $(1, -1)$.

Thus follows $\mathbb{C}^* \cong U_1 \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}^*$.

Comment: Replace everywhere $\Bbb R^*$ by $\Bbb R_+^*.$ Suppress everywhere this useless $2\pi.$ Prove 3 before 2, and no need to use exp. Write directly $f(r_1,z_1)(r_2,z_2))=\dots.$ In 2) good idea to use ker, now that you have proved 3: suppose $rz=1$, then $(r,z)=(1,1).$

Comment: do you mean I have to delete the $2\pi$ and the exponent? but what becomes $e^{2\pi i x} $ ? $ix$?

Comment: I mean that you first can replace everywhere $e^{2\pi ix}$ by $e^{ix}$, and that you can even replace everywhere the former or the latter by $z\in U_1$. You do no need to add the $x$'s, you can directly multiply the $z$'s.

Comment: Your injectivity argument is incorrect. $(1,1)$ maps to the same element as $(-1,-1)$.

Comment: Ah you are right. Do you know how I can change it? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: You can change it to a correct statement. As written, it is false. Note that $\mathbb{C}^*$ has only two elements that satisfy $x^2=e$ (the identity of the group), namely $x=1$ and $x=-1$. But $U\times\mathbb{R}^*$ has four: $(1,1)$, $(1,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, and $(-1,-1)$. They are not isomorphic. The correct statement, as @Anne Bauval noted, is that $\mathbb{C}^*$ is isomorphic to $U\times\mathbb{R}^*_{+}$, the circle group times the multiplicative group of *positive* real numbers.

Comment: I see it was my fault I have changed it

Comment: You should also edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proof is correct, but it can be simplified.

1. There is no reason to write the elements of $U_1$ in the form $e^{2\pi i x}$. Simply define
   $$f(r,z) = r \cdot z .$$
2. That $f$ is a homomorphism follows from the commutativy of complex multiplication:
   $$f((r_1,z_1) \cdot (r_2,z_2) = f(r_1r_2, z_1z_2) = r_1r_2z_1z_2 = r_1z_1r_2z_2 = f(r_1,z_1) \cdot f(r_2,z_2) .$$
3. To see that $f$ is a bijection, consider
   $$g :  \mathbb C^* \to \mathbb R _{>0} \times U_1, g(w) = \left(\lvert w \rvert, \frac {w}{\lvert w \rvert} \right).$$
   It is then easy to check that $g \circ f = id$ and $f \circ g = id$.